# 深度センサーから得られた距離情報の中から最小値を出力したい

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

```
cout<<min(depth[i])<<endl;
```

でやってみたのですがうまくいかなかったです

```
#include"stdafx.h"     
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

NUI_LOCKED_RECT depthData = { 0 };
depthFrame.pFrameTexture->LockRect(0, &depthData, 0, 0);
USHORT* depth = (USHORT*)depthData.pBits;

LONG registX = 0;
LONG registY = 0;
cv::Mat bufferMat = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_16UC1);
ushort* pBuffer = reinterpret_cast<ushort*>(depthData.pBits);
ushort bb[307200];

for (int yy = 0; yy < 480; yy++) {
    for (int xx = 0; xx < 640; xx++) {
        unsigned int index = yy * 640 + xx;
        bb[index] = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(pBuffer[index]);
    }
}
for (int y = 0; y < 480; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 640; x++) {
        kinect->NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution(CAMERA_RESOLUTION, CAMERA_RESOLUTION, 0, x, y, *depth, &registX, &registY);
        if ((registX >= 0) && (registX < 640) && (registY >= 0) && (registY < 480)) {
            bufferMat.at<ushort>(registY, registX) = *depth;
        }
        depth++;

        int index = x + y * width;
        int z = bb[index];
        //printf("ピクセル番号x %d ||y %d, 距離情報%d \n", x,y, bb[index]);
        cout<<min(bb[index])<<endl;
```

エラー

```
オーバートードされた関数minのインスタンスが引数リストが一致しません（引数の型　ushort)
```

Comment: `depth[i]`の型を明記ください。もし同型が`cv::Mat`であれば[`cv::minMaxLoc`関数](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707)が求める機能に近いかもしれません。使い方はリファレンスをご参考に。

Comment: int型です！またはushort型？だと思います！

Comment: depth[i]としてましたが実際はbb[index]でした。

Comment: 質問の際は「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)」を載せることを心がけてください。この質問であればヘッダファイルの定義部分なども必要かと思います。

Comment: 最小値を求めたいなら`min()`には比較のため2つ以上の値を渡す必要があるように思いますが、質問のコードでは`min(bb[index])`で **単一** の引数しか渡していないように見えます。 - 参考: [std::min](http://kaworu.jpn.org/cpp/std::min)

Comment: depthのセンサーから得られた距離のデータだけしかなく比較対象がないです。そもそものminの関数が今回に適していないという事でしょうか

Comment: 「比較対象がない」はタイトルの「センサーから得られた膨大な距離情報の中から最小値を出力したい」との説明と矛盾しませんか？

Answer (score 1):

文言「最小」ってことは「複数個の中で」最小ってことです。これに対して提示コード `ushort bb[307200];` に `min(bb[index])` では「１つ」しか値を渡していないのでコンパイラに怒られています。

最小値を求める [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 標準ライブラリ関数は `std::min` と `std::min_element` の２つがあって、提示例の場合は `std::min_element` のほうが自然かも。

```
#define elementsof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(0[a]))
ushort const* minp = std::min_element(bb+0, bb+elementsof(bb));
std::cout << *minp << std::endl;
```

で最小値を表示することができるでしょう。

で、上記コードをどこに置くべきか、なんですが、提示コードでは最小値をループ内で毎回求めていますが、見る限り `bb` はループ内で変化していないので無駄無駄無駄無駄です。最小値を求めるコードはループ外に置いて、求めた最小値（のコピー）をループ内で使いましょう。

# 提示コード中 `307200` という値は `640*480` としたほうがわかりやすいだろうとか
 # そもそも `640` などと魔法の数字を複数回数ソースコードに書くのはダメダメとか
 # `bb` は 600KiB の大きさがあるので Win32 のスタックに置くのはぎりぎりとか
 # その辺のつっこみ始めると止まらないので独り言モードで。